# Regular expression - what is my mistake?

Tags: regex

I would like to match either any sequence or digits, or the literal: na .
I am using:

```
"^\d*|na$"
```

Numbers are being matched, but not na.

Whats my mistake?

More info: im using this in a regular expression validator for a textbox in aspnet c#.

A blank entry is ok.

Comment: Would be nice if you post string you're trying to match against

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because the expression is being read (assuming PCRE):

```
"^\d*" OR "na$"
```

Some parentheses would take care of that in a jiff. Choose from (depending on your needs):

```
"^(\d+|na)$"    // this will capture the number or na
"^(?:\d+|na)$"  // this one won't capture
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

The `|` operator have a higher precedence than the anchors `^` and `$`. So the expression `^\d*|na$` means match `^\d*` or `na$`. So try this:

```
^(\d*|na)$
```

Or:

```
^\d*$|^na$
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `^(?:\d*|na)$` would be better. What language/engine? Also, please show the input and, if possible, the snippet of the code.

Also, it is possible that you aren't matching "na" because there is a new line after it. The digits wouldn't be affected because you did not specify a $ anchor for them.

So, depending on the language and how the input is acquired, there might be  new-line between "na" and the end of the string, and $ won't match it unless you turn on multi-line match (or strip the string of the new line).

Answer (score -2):

This may not be the *best* or most elegant way to fix it, but try this:

```
"^\d*|[n][a]$"
```